# bridge a connection and keep same ip and subnet

Tags: 12.04, server, network-bridge

I have googled this for a while now but am not able to find answer to this question. I have my xbox bridged to my ubuntu pc. Everything works, maybe just gives an nat error now and then. I want to be able to system link or share files from my computer. My setup is a wireless dongle conected to the ubuntu pc sharing the connecting through network-manager. My routers ip adress is set up as 192.168.1.1 with a subnet of 255.255.255.0.

Comment: I dont understand the question, what is the current setup and what dö you want?

Comment: Sorry. Let me better phrase my question. I have my Xbox connected to my Ubuntu PC. It is sharing the connection through the normal method which by using the network manager. This PC has a wireless dongle and is connected to my router. My problem is that ubuntu creates its own network for the Ethernet connection (xbox). I want the xbox to be under the same network as my router. This is so that I can use services such as windows media center or any other service that requires the xbox to be under the same network as the device.